# How can I automatically detect proxy settings from system service

Tags: c#, windows, service, proxy

My program is running by system service and it should use the proxy settings, the problem they set for the users. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

and here is a link: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My program running under the user "system" as service so it does not return anything with this function. This function working grate when I'm run it from any local user.